# TypeError when using cartopy to plot xarray pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I'm trying to use cartopy and matplotlib to plot a pcolormesh map of some climate data.

My data array looks like:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 180, lon: 360)>
array([[6.32820411, 6.42046823, 6.45543426, ..., 6.5081467 , 6.4075159 ,
        6.33443656],
       [5.28489672, 5.19856368, 5.24061779, ..., 5.73291287, 5.51586312,
        5.32528716],
       [5.91536731, 6.12045649, 6.29024142, ..., 6.51405566, 6.23179869,
        5.92291649],
       ...,
       [9.29038684, 9.37438885, 9.46411405, ..., 9.37909437, 9.3296219 ,
        9.29826895],
       [9.15633226, 9.26943725, 9.25708442, ..., 8.94799361, 9.03535374,
        9.03494086],
       [9.42117899, 9.47583389, 9.44276634, ..., 9.09316031, 9.19251157,
        9.31624963]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 ... 355.5 356.5 357.5 358.5 359.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 -85.5 ... 86.5 87.5 88.5 89.5
```

To plot this, I've tried a number of approaches, but I always get the same error...

**Example:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Mollweide()})

ax.pcolormesh(da.lon, da.lat, da.values, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Then I get the error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-95ebedde5dbf> in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Mollweide()})
      2 
----> 3 ax.pcolormesh(plot_da.lon, plot_da.lat, plot_da.values, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

~/miniconda3/envs/BASIC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py in pcolormesh(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1457                              ' consider using PlateCarree/RotatedPole.')
   1458         kwargs.setdefault('transform', t)
-> 1459         result = self._pcolormesh_patched(*args, **kwargs)
   1460         self.autoscale_view()
   1461         return result

~/miniconda3/envs/BASIC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py in _pcolormesh_patched(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1489         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   1490 
-> 1491         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   1492         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   1493 

TypeError: _pcolorargs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allmatch'
```

This error makes no sense to me, has anyone else had it?

Versions:

`matplotlib`: 3.3.0

`xarray`: 0.15.1

`cartopy`: 0.17.0

Comment: It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1615) in cartopy; try updating to version 0.18.0.

Comment: Aaah epic! Cheers :)